# JQuery Datatable-Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, nullreferenceexception

**Scenario:** I have 2 different datatables in 2 tabs.
On clicking on tabs, I am showing/hiding the divs and the corresponding datatable.

On document.Ready, I am initializing the datatables. It works fine now. But, when I switch from one tab to another tab and then resize the browser window, I am getting the following error in console:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is
>   null or undefined

**I am getting the error in datatable.min.js(version 1.10.10). Attached is the screen shot of error:**[image: datatable.min.js(line number:213)]

The initialization of the datatable is as:

```
var $employeeTable,
     savedPage ;
function initalizeEmp() {
    $employeeTable = $('#employee').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "order": [[1, "desc"]],
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25], [10, 25]],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 4,
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                if ($(data).attr('results-grid') != "")
                    return '<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="window.open(\'../School/DownloadEmp.aspx?EmpID=' + $(data).attr('results-grid') + '\')" target="_blank">' + data + '</a>';
                    //return '<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="EmpLink(' + $(data).attr('results-grid') + ')">' + data + '</a>';
                else
                    return data;
            }, "orderable": true
        },
        {
            'bSortable': false,"targets": [0]
        },
        { type: 'date-mm-dd-yyyy', targets: 1 },
        {
            'bSortable': false,"targets": [6]
        },
        {
            'bSortable': false,"targets": [7]
        },
        {
            'bSortable': false,"targets": [8]
        }
        ],
        fnInitComplete: function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (typeof savedPage !== 'undefined') {
                    $employeeTable.page(savedPage).draw(false);
                }
                //$('body').vtUnmask();
            }, 10);
        }
    });

    $('#employee').on('page.dt', function () {
        savedPage = $employeeTable.page();
        $('input[id*="_checkBox"]').attr('checked', false);
    });
 }
```

Comment: Is the error associated with a specific line in your code?

Comment: Try the same exact code, but without the comma after the square bracket at the end of your table properties. `...    'bSortable': false,"targets": [8]
        }
        ],` <-this one

Comment: Hi @jonmrich,Thanks for your reply I tried without comma, but still it's not working. I have added the screenshot of the error as well. Kindly check it out.

Comment: Got it...this is almost certainly caused by you having the wrong number of columns. If you are defining the columns in your HTML and have a different number of columns in your datatables initiation, then you'll get this error. What's your HTML for the table look like?

Answer (score 0):

your problem happens in the render:

```
      "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
            if ($(data).attr('results-grid') != "")
                return '<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="window.open(\'../School/DownloadEmp.aspx?EmpID=' + $(data).attr('results-grid') + '\')" target="_blank">' + data + '</a>';
                //return '<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="EmpLink(' + $(data).attr('results-grid') + ')">' + data + '</a>';
            else
                return data;
        }
```

You want accessing attribute 'results-grid' but `$(data)` is not a html element is the value, to access the td element, you can use `fnCreateCell`.

```
       "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
            if ($(nTd).attr('results-grid') != "")
            {
                return '<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="window.open(\'../School/DownloadEmp.aspx?EmpID=' + $(nTd).attr('results-grid') + '\')" target="_blank">' + sData + '</a>';
            }else{
                return sData;
            }
        }
```

example : https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/3/

Comment: Hi @CMedina, Thanks for your reply.
I tried the code suggested by you, but it's not working.
I have added the screenshot of the issue found in datatable.min.js(version 1.10.10). Kindly check it out. Let me know, if you need more information.

Comment: @PranavKumar you can show your code html of your tabs to help!